# If $f:X\to\mathbb{C}$ is integrable, is it $|\int f|\le \int |f|$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,S,\mu)$ be a measurable space. We say that $f:X\to\mathbb{C}$ is integrable if $Im(f)$ and $Re(f)$ are integrable, and we put $\int f :=\int Im(f)+i\int Re(f)$.

Is it true that $|\int f|\le \int |f|$?

I don't see if this is true, because:

$|\int f| = \sqrt{(\int Im(f))^2+(\int Re(f))^2}$ and $\int |f|=\int \sqrt{Im(f)^2+Re(f)^2}$

Could this be false?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $\int f = r e^{i\theta}$.  Then
$$ \left|\int f\right| = \text{Re}\left(e^{-i\theta} \int f\right) = \int \text{Re}(e^{-i\theta} f) \le \int |f| .$$

Comment: Thanks! @StephenMontgomery-S